# How to get multidimensional array from yii 'CDbDataReader::readAll'

Tags: php, mysql, yii

It is two tables in a database. The first tablse contains a list of products, and the second contains a list of options. For one product may be several options. I have built next query with yii query bulder

```
SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`id`,
                `p`.`name`,
                `pc`.`category_id`,
                `c`.`name` AS `category_name`,
                `ov`.`value_str` AS `option_value`
FROM `cms_product` `p`
LEFT JOIN `cms_product_category` `pc` ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN `cms_category` `c` ON c.id = pc.category_id
LEFT JOIN `cms_product_option_set` `pos` ON p.id = pos.product_id
LEFT JOIN `cms_option_variant` `ov` ON ov.id=pos.option_variant_id
ORDER BY `p`.`id` ASC LIMIT 100
```

But yii function 'CDbDataReader::readAll()' returns only one option for each product. If I execute this query in MySQL it works good. How I can get right result with yii

Answer (score 0):

Use `queryAll()` method like below:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`id`,
            `p`.`name`,
            `pc`.`category_id`,
            `c`.`name` AS `category_name`,
            `ov`.`value_str` AS `option_value`
FROM `cms_product` `p`
LEFT JOIN `cms_product_category` `pc` ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN `cms_category` `c` ON c.id = pc.category_id
LEFT JOIN `cms_product_option_set` `pos` ON p.id = pos.product_id
LEFT JOIN `cms_option_variant` `ov` ON ov.id=pos.option_variant_id
ORDER BY `p`.`id` ASC LIMIT 100";
```

Then:

```
$result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

This will return you an array with the result.

Comment: As of http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryAll-detail it must work!